# check all checkboxes and reverse if one item is checked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form with multiple groups of checkboxes. I have one checkbox in each group that is a select/deselect all checkbox. I have been using the following function to enact a selectall deselectall  and changing class on each of the inputs parents item, a button. What is the best way going forward to remove the checkall selection of the checkbox and remove and add a class if one item from the list that is not the checkall checkbox is chosen, and then reversed if person chooses all checkboxes or the checkall checkbox. I have been saving $(this) as a variable. Is this going to be an issue?

.html

```
<div class="panel-body">
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 margin-bottom-sm">
        <label for="checkall4" class="btn btn-custom btn-sm btn-block">
            <input type="checkbox" name="checkall4" id="checkall4" data-mini="true" class="checkall" checked>
                Select/Deselect All</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 margin-bottom-sm">
        <label for="within1" class="btn btn-custom btn-sm btn-block">
            <input type="checkbox" name="within1" value="1" checked="checked" id="within1"/>
                Within 1km</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-xs-6 col-sm-4 margin-bottom-sm">
        <label for="within2" class="btn btn-custom btn-sm btn-block">
            <input type="checkbox" name="within2" value="2" checked="checked" id="within2"/>
                Within 2km</label>
    </div>
</div>
```

.js

```
$('.checkall').change(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    var $allBoxes = $this.closest('.panel-body').find(':checkbox');
    if ($this.prop('checked')) {
        $allBoxes.prop('checked', true);
        $allBoxes.parent().removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-custom');
    } else {
        $allBoxes.prop('checked', false);
        $allBoxes.parent().removeClass('btn-custom').addClass('btn-default');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add another handler for handler non checkall checkboxes

```
$('.panel-body input[type="checkbox"]:not(.checkall)').change(function () {
    var $this = $(this),
        $body = $this.closest('.panel-body');
    var $allBoxes = $body.find(':checkbox:not(.checkall)');
    $body.find('.checkall').prop('checked', $allBoxes.not(':checked').length == 0);
})
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/9FkPr/)

Comment: this is working perfectly. Only thing where would i add `.removeClass('btn-custom').addClass('btn-default')` to the selected element and the checkall element, and then reverse if checkall activated `.removeClass('btn-default').addClass('btn-custom')`

Comment: that nailed it! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

use this **javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".checkall").click(function () {
        $(".classofcheckbox").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
    });
});
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/2BFq7/)